# Odd Factorial Method

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, factorial

I got an assignment need to do the following:   If the input is even, return 0.  Otherwise, returns the factorial of the integer input, but without multiplying any even numbers. and i wrote down some quote but it run with error. Can someone tell me where i did wrong?

```
public static int oddFactorial(int number){

    if (number%2==0)
        return (0);
else{
        int counter = 1;
        int toReturn= 1;
        while (counter <= number)
            toReturn = toReturn*counter;
            counter+=2;

        return number;
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
int number = 7;

}

}
```

Comment: You didn't call oddFactorial() in main().

Comment: `it run with error.` I bet it didn't

Comment: it print out nothing.

Comment: You never called it from main

Comment: so right now i put the main at the end?

Comment: The order doesn't matter. You have to _call_ the function.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language.

Comment: what do you mean tag the question?

Comment: Check my answer. It should work for you now.

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do. Check the highlighted line.You are calling `oddFactorial` method and displaying its result. The order of `oddFactorial` and main doesn't matter you need to call the method from `main`.

```
public static int oddFactorial(int number){

            if (number%2==0){
                return (0);}              
                int counter = 1;
                int toReturn= 1;
                while (counter <= number){
                    toReturn = toReturn*counter;
                    counter+=2;
                }
                return toReturn;          
            }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
             int number = 7;
           **System.out.println(oddFactorial(number));**

         }

     }
```

Comment: it worked, but it print out nothing. Is there any mistake with my else statement?

Comment: You need to return `toReturn` instead of `number` from you method. Check my code. If it works accept the answer.

Comment: finally it worked!! I have to thank you so much!!!!!